# Elasticsearch. Remove stopwords from query - good or bad idea?

Tags: elasticsearch

We remove stopwords when indexing but find that "x and y" returns different results to "x y".

So, is removing stopwords from query terms a good or bad idea? When we tried we found that "+x" was reduced to "x" by the "stop" analyzer...hence, makes me think we are on the wrong track.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at my answer, would be great if you can comment  :)

Comment: Had a look but we have left as-is for now. If our clients complain then may have to revisit. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an article you should read: https://www.elastic.co/blog/stop-stopping-stop-words-a-look-at-common-terms-query

It really depends on what your domain is and what kind of queries you'll be executing.

I no longer remove stop words because they contain a lot of semantic meaning and removing them might bring back undesired results. Instead, it's better to build your own list of stop words that are applicable to your domain.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Evaldas, it totally depends on your domain and use-case, but if you don't have a complete clarity on this, I would suggest not to remove them, please refer this [awesome magneto blog](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/es-config-stopwords.html) on various aspect of stop-words, like [performance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stopwords.html), [pros and cons of stop words](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pros-cons-stopwords.html) etc